# Finding whether a row in a table is visible or not in code behind in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've a Grid View where I bind the rows of the Grid View and make only the first row visible to the user using row.Style["Display"] = "none" for the rest of the rows other than the first row. Then, I make the rest of the rows visible using jquery. At the bottom of the GridView, I have a Button and now in the button click event, I've to find the rows that are visible to the user. I'm using the below code to know which rows are visible to the user in the code behind but it returns only the first row.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCheckPoints.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (row.Style["Display"] != "none")
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there is another way of achieving this goal.

You can have a hidden field in each row which you can set to 1 or 0 and you can find that field's value like

((HtmlInputHidden)row.FindControl('HiddenCtrl')).value.Equals()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *changed* the state of GridView rows in `Javascript`. On postback the state of `GridView` is loaded from `ViewState` which is not changed by the `Javascript`. Therefore you are not getting the rows that are being made visible by `Javascript`. You can store the indexes/ids of rows in some hidden field and later get that hidden field on server side. You will need to make hidden field `runat="server"`

*Html*

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdn" runat="server" />
```

*JavaScript*

```
document.getElementById("hdn").value = "1,0,0,1"; //here first and four rows are visible
```

*Code behind*

```
string hdnValue = hdn.Value;
```